# exception handling not outputting to dbms

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my sql code for a function that calculates the area of a circle. I am having trouble getting a dbms_output to show the user defined exception.

I begin by declaring an exception underzero. then i raise it if the user inputs a number less than or equal to 0. In the exception i have dbms_output then return the result. It shows in the query result that the value is null, however the output isn't showing.

I have already set serveroutput on and set verify off. I don't know why it wont output anything. If i run that line alone it outputs to the dbms output window but not when the exception is raised.

```
create or replace function circle_area
  (p_radius number)
  return number
is
  c_Pi Constant number := acos(-1);
  v_result number(10, 2);
  underzero exception;
begin
  if p_radius <=0 then
    raise underzero;
  else
    v_result := c_pi * p_radius * p_radius;
    return v_result;
  end if;

exception
 when underzero then
    dbms_output.put_line('enter number greater than 0');
    return v_result;
 when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('Exception Location: Anonymous Block');
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode || ': ' || sqlerrm);
    return v_result;
end circle_area;
```

to call the function:

```
select circle_area(-2) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the problem.  The code you posted will generate output to `dbms_output` if serveroutput is enabled...

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> create or replace function circle_area
  2    (p_radius number)
  3    return number
  4  is
  5    c_Pi Constant number := acos(-1);
  6    v_result number(10, 2);
  7    underzero exception;
  8  begin
  9    if p_radius <=0 then
 10      raise underzero;
 11    else
 12      v_result := c_pi * p_radius * p_radius;
 13      return v_result;
 14    end if;
 15
 16  exception
 17   when underzero then
 18      dbms_output.put_line('enter number greater than 0');
 19      return v_result;
 20   when others then
 21      dbms_output.put_line('Exception Location: Anonymous Block');
 22      dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode || ': ' || sqlerrm);
 23      return v_result;
 24  end circle_area;
 25  /

Function created.

SQL> select circle_area(-2) from dual;

CIRCLE_AREA(-2)
---------------


enter number greater than 0
```

I'm assuming that this is part of a homework assignment and not a real problem that you're facing.  In reality, you'd never write code whose primary purpose was to write to `dbms_output` and you would never, ever have an exception handler that only wrote to `dbms_output`.